# Xaml snippets Visual studio 2019 (created but does not work)

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, xamarin

wondering if is possible to create xaml snippets
I have vs 2019,given I have created the below xaml snippet

Why is it when in visual studio xamarin project typing "grd" and tabbing nothing happens?
can somebody clarify whether the location and the snippet is correct?

**Also what is the difference between codetemplate vs codesnippet?**

Also if you any samples how todo in resharper that would be good too.

**links** 
http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2013/07/08/xaml-code-snippets-for-visual-studio.aspx

Location:

C:\Users\myName\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Code Snippets\XAML\My XAML Snippets

Snippets

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <CodeTemplates version="3.0">
      <CodeTemplate version="2.0">
        <Header>
          <_Group>Xml</_Group>
          <Version />
          <MimeType>application/xaml+xml</MimeType>
          <Shortcut>grd</Shortcut>
          <_Description>Grid Template</_Description>
          <TemplateType>Expansion, SurroundsWith</TemplateType>
        </Header>
        <Variables />
        <Code Language="XAML"><![CDATA[<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        $selected$$end$
    </Grid>]]></Code>
      </CodeTemplate>
    </CodeTemplates>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> wondering if is possible to create xaml snippets I have vs 2019

I followed this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/walkthrough-creating-a-code-snippet?view=vs-2019) and created a code snippet successfully, here are steps:

**1**.Create a new XML file in Visual Studio and add the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippets xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
  <CodeSnippet  Format="1.0.0">
    <Header>
      <Title>1213test</Title>
      <Shortcut>grd</Shortcut>
    </Header>
    <Snippet>
      <Code Language="XAML">
        <![CDATA[<Grid>
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
              <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          $selected$$end$
      </Grid>]]>
      </Code>
    </Snippet>
  </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

**2**.Save the file with name `MyCodeSnippet.snippet`(not .xml).

**3**.Create a new project and go to `Tools` > `Code Snippets Manager` > `import` > find the `MyCodeSnippet.snippet` you just created > `open` > `finish`. (described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/walkthrough-creating-a-code-snippet?view=vs-2019#add-a-code-snippet-to-visual-studio))

**4**.Open a xaml file and Type `grd` in the file and press Tab **twice**.(Note: **twice**), then it works.

Here are documents you can read:

[snippets-vsmac-2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/snippets?view=vsmac-2019)

[walkthrough-creating-a-code-snippet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/walkthrough-creating-a-code-snippet?view=vs-2019)

> Also what is the difference between codetemplate vs codesnippet

I did some research but can't any documentation about `codetemplate`.